# PHP Foreach and string concatenation

Tags: php, string, foreach, concatenation

Using two associative arrays and a nested foreach loop, I want to echo this text:

```
1abcd
2abcd
3abcd
4abcd
```

But somehow, I just get `4d`. I have reviewed the code several times and I know that it must be something very simple, but I can't find the problem.

```
<?php
$output = "";
$list1 = array('1' => '1', '1' => '2', '1' => '3', '1' => '4');
$list2 = array('a' => 'a', 'a' => 'b', 'a' => 'c', 'a' => 'd');

foreach($list1 as $key1 => $value1)
{   
    $letters = '';
        foreach($list2 as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        $letters .= $value2;
    }
   $output .= $value1;
   $output .= $letters . '<br>';
}

echo $output;
```

Please, help me solving this problem!!
Thank you

Comment: You can't have multiple entries in an array with the same key: `$list1 = array('1' => '1', '1' => '2', '1' => '3', '1' => '4');` defines 4 entries in the array, each with the same key (`1`); `$list2 = array('a' => 'a', 'a' => 'b', 'a' => 'c', 'a' => 'd');` defines 4 entries, all with the same key (`a`)..... why are you even defining keys anyway? You don't need to do so

Comment: @Mark Baker This is an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your array, do this

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($list1);
echo "</pre>";
```

It will return this

```
Array
(
[1] => 4
)
1
```

In order to get the answer you want, first you need to adjust your associative array to something like this

```
$list1 = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4');
$list2 = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c', 'd' => 'd');
```

Then you can go ahead and do this

```
$array = array();
foreach($list1 as $key1 => $value1){

$letters = '';
foreach($list2 as $key2 => $value2){
    $letters .= $value2;
}
$output .= $value1;
$output .= $letters . '<br>';

}

echo $output;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have another look at your array
`$list1 = array('1' => '1', '1' => '2', '1' => '3', '1' => '4');
 $list2 = array('a' => 'a', 'a' => 'b', 'a' => 'c', 'a' => 'd');
 print_r($list1);
 print_r($list2);`

You've created an associated array with the same key, so really all you've done is `$list1 = array('1'=>'4')` and `$list2 = array('a'=>'d')`

Answer (score -1):

Note that you say you are building an associative array, "associative" means each "unique" key will have a value. In your array you are overriding over and over your values, remember, the key is like the "place" you want to store the value. If you store a different value in the same place or key it will be overridden.

the correct way:

```
$list1 = array('0' => '1', '1' => '2', '2' => '3', '3' => '4');
$list2 = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c', 'd' => 'd');
```

If you see there is a different place or key for each value.

If you run your code it should work now. And if you pay attention you will notice you don't even need letters as keys.

```
$list1 = array('0' => '1', '1' => '2', '2' => '3', '3' => '4');
$list2 = array('0' => 'a', '1' => 'b', '2' => 'c', '3' => 'd');
```

By trying both you will understand more about arrays. This is the very basics.